# Desktop client for local OSM Server

Tags: openstreetmap, desktop-gis

I've just installed a local Open Street Map server. Is there a simple desktop client (win or linux), which can connect to local OSM server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a tile sever:

- Any browser
- [Marble](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/KDE_Marble)
- [QLandkarteGT](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin/QLandkarte)
- Various other software from the [list of desktop software for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about tile-server. How use Marble for local connection?

Comment: You can add your own tile server via *File -> Add a New Map -> Online map providing indexed tiles*. Simply add your tile server URL in the form of `http://youraddress/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png`